# XSL For-Each Looping

Tags: xml, xslt, loops, xpath, foreach

Basically this is my XML taken from an excerpt of a Shakespeare play:

```
<PLAY>
<PERSONA>BENEDICK, a young lord of Padua.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>LEONATO, governor of Messina.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>ANTONIO, his brother.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>BALTHASAR, attendant on Don Pedro.</PERSONA>
<PGROUP>
    <PERSONA>CONRADE</PERSONA>
    <PERSONA>BORACHIO</PERSONA>
    <GRPDESCR>followers of Don John.</GRPDESCR>
</PGROUP>
<PERSONA>FRIAR FRANCIS</PERSONA>
</PLAY>
```

Here's the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="PLAY">
    <html>
    <body>
         <xsl:for-each select="PERSONAE">

              <xsl:apply-templates select="PERSONA" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="PGROUP/PERSONA" />

          </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PERSONA">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PGROUP/PERSONA">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="." />, </p> 
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="..">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="GRPDESCR" /></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The current HTML output:

```
BENEDICK, a young lord of Padua.

LEONATO, governor of Messina.

ANTONIO, his brother.

BALTHASAR, attendant on Don Pedro.

FRIAR FRANCIS

CONRADE,

followers of Don John.

BORACHIO,

followers of Don John.
```

And this is what I want my HTML output to look like:

```
BENEDICK, a young lord of Padua.

LEONATO, governor of Messina.

ANTONIO, his brother.

BALTHASAR, attendant on Don Pedro.

FRIAR FRANCIS

CONRADE, BORACHIO, followers of Don John.
```

I've spent hours on this so any help would be so great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your XSLT you are attempting to use `xsl:for-each` to iterate over `PERSONAE`, but your sample XML does not contain a `PERSONAE` element. Unless there is more to your XSLT that you are not showing, you should not have any output other than `<html>
   <body></body>
</html>`

Rather than using `xsl:for-each`, you could achieve the desired output more simply by using a "push" style that uses `xsl:apply-templates` and specific templates to match and generate desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="PLAY">
        <html>
            <body>
                <!--first, process all PERSONA elements 
                    that are children of PLAY-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PERSONA" />
                <!--Then, process all PGROUP elements -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PGROUP" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--generic template match for PERSONA elements -->
    <xsl:template match="PERSONA">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--For each PGROUP matched, create a P and apply templates 
        to child elements(i.e. PERSONA and GRPDESCR) -->
    <xsl:template match="PGROUP">
        <p>
            <!--Note: No specific template is defined for GRPDESCR. 
               The default XSLT template rules will apply for GRPDESCR 
               and it will copy it's text to output -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </p> 
    </xsl:template>

    <!--A more specific match for PERSONA elements that will select the text 
        and then add ", " -->
    <xsl:template match="PGROUP/PERSONA">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```